# JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames for deserialization

Tags: serialization, servicestack, deserialization, servicestack-text

I need lowercase_underscore_names for my REST client.

`JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames` setting works fine only for serialization (JSON).

Now I use `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes to deserialize my models correctly.

But is there any generic way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly is not working? your question is a little difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JsConfig.PropertyConvention = JsonPropertyConvention.Lenient;
```

The answer.